# 2 models in 1 view MVC4

Tags: c#, linq, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I have two models as shown below:

One:

```
 [Validator(typeof(BlogPostValidator))]
    public partial class BlogPostModel : BaseNopEntityModel
    {
        public BlogPostModel()
        {
            Tags = new List<string>();
            Comments = new List<BlogCommentModel>();
            AddNewComment = new AddBlogCommentModel();
        }

        public string SeName { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Body { get; set; }

        public bool AllowComments { get; set; }

        public int NumberOfComments { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        public IList<string> Tags { get; set; }

        public IList<BlogCommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
        public AddBlogCommentModel AddNewComment { get; set; }

        public BlogCommentModel blogcommentmodel { get; set; }
    }
```

two:

```
 public partial class BlogCommentModel : BaseNopEntityModel
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }

        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        public string CustomerAvatarUrl { get; set; }

        public string CommentText { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

        public bool AllowViewingProfiles { get; set; }

        public int CommentParentID { get; set; }

        public IList<BlogComment> ChildCommentList { get; set; }//netra
    }
```

I want to make use of **ChildCommentList** from **BlogCommentModel** to show nested comments.

My View:

```
@model BlogPostModel
@using Nop.Web.Models.Blogs;
 @if (Model.AllowComments)
        {
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
            <fieldset class="new-comment" id="addcomment">
                <legend class="title">@T("Blog.Comments.LeaveYourComment")</legend>
                @using (Html.BeginForm())
                {
                    <div>
                        <div class="message-error">@Html.ValidationSummary(true)</div>
                        @{
                    string result = TempData["nop.blog.addcomment.result"] as string;
                        }
                        @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
                        {
                            <div class="result">@result</div>
                        }
                        <div class="forms-box">
                            <div class="inputs">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddNewComment.CommentText)
                                <div class="input-box">
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.AddNewComment.CommentText, new { @class = "comment-text" })
                                </div>
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddNewComment.CommentText)
                            </div>
                            @if (Model.AddNewComment.DisplayCaptcha)
                            {
                                <div class="captcha-box">
                                    @Html.Raw(Html.GenerateCaptcha())
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear">
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                        <div class="clear">
                        </div>
                        <div class="buttons">
                            <input type="submit" name="add-comment" class="button-1 blog-post-add-comment-button" value="@T("Blog.Comments.SubmitButton")" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </fieldset>
                if (Model.Comments.Count > 0)
                {
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
            <div class="comment-list">
                <div class="title">
                    @T("Blog.Comments")
                </div>
                <div class="clear">
                </div>
                @foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
                {
                    <div class="blog-comment">
                        <div class="comment-info">
                            <div class="user-info">
                                @if (comment.AllowViewingProfiles)
                                {
                                    <a href="@Url.RouteUrl("CustomerProfile", new { id = comment.CustomerId })" class="username">@(comment.CustomerName)</a>
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    <span class="username">@(comment.CustomerName)</span>
                                }
                                <div class="avatar">
                                    @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(comment.CustomerAvatarUrl))
                                    {
                                        <img src="@(comment.CustomerAvatarUrl)" class="avatar-img" title="avatar" alt="avatar" />
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="comment-content">
                            <div class="comment-time">
                                @T("Blog.Comments.CreatedOn"): <span class="stat-value">@comment.CreatedOn.ToString("g")</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="comment-body">
                                @Html.Raw(Nop.Core.Html.HtmlHelper.FormatText(comment.CommentText, false, true, false, false, false, false))
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @Html.Widget("blogpost_page_inside_comment")
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                    <div>
                     @foreach(var childcomments in Model.blogcommentmodel.ChildCommentList)
                     {
                      @Html.Raw(Nop.Core.Html.HtmlHelper.FormatText(childcomments.CommentText, false, true, false, false, false, false))
                     }
                    </div>
                }
                <div class="buttons">
                    <input type="submit" id="replyto" name="reply-comment" class="button-1 blog-post-add-comment-button" value="@T("Blog.Comments.ReplyButton")" />
                </div>
            </div>
                }
        }
```

Error occurred on :

```
@foreach(var childcomments in Model.blogcommentmodel.ChildCommentList)
                         {
                          @Html.Raw(Nop.Core.Html.HtmlHelper.FormatText(childcomments.CommentText, false, true, false, false, false, false))
                         }
                        </div>
                    }
```

NullReferenceException was unhandled by usercode -{"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

My controller code for ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult BlogPost(int blogPostId)
        {
            if (!_blogSettings.Enabled)
                return RedirectToRoute("HomePage");

            var blogPost = _blogService.GetBlogPostById(blogPostId);
            if (blogPost == null ||
                (blogPost.StartDateUtc.HasValue && blogPost.StartDateUtc.Value >= DateTime.UtcNow) ||
                (blogPost.EndDateUtc.HasValue && blogPost.EndDateUtc.Value <= DateTime.UtcNow))
                return RedirectToRoute("HomePage");

            var model = new BlogPostModel();
            **PrepareBlogPostModel(model, blogPost, true);**

            return View(model);
        }
```

Below method called in above ActionResult:

```
 [NonAction]
        protected void PrepareBlogPostModel(BlogPostModel model, BlogPost blogPost, bool prepareComments)
        {
            if (blogPost == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("blogPost");

            if (model == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("model");

            model.Id = blogPost.Id;
            model.SeName = blogPost.GetSeName();
            model.Title = blogPost.Title;
            model.Body = blogPost.Body;
            model.AllowComments = blogPost.AllowComments;
            model.CreatedOn = _dateTimeHelper.ConvertToUserTime(blogPost.CreatedOnUtc, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            model.Tags = blogPost.ParseTags().ToList();
            model.NumberOfComments = blogPost.ApprovedCommentCount;
            model.AddNewComment.DisplayCaptcha = _captchaSettings.Enabled && _captchaSettings.ShowOnBlogCommentPage;
            if (prepareComments)
            {
               // var blogchildcomment = _blogService.GetAllChildComments();
                var blogComments = blogPost.BlogComments.Where(pr => pr.IsApproved).OrderBy(pr => pr.CreatedOnUtc);
                foreach (var bc in blogComments)
                {
                    var commentModel = new BlogCommentModel()
                    {
                        Id = bc.Id,
                        CustomerId = bc.CustomerId,
                        CustomerName = bc.Customer.FormatUserName(),
                        CommentText = bc.CommentText,
                        CreatedOn = _dateTimeHelper.ConvertToUserTime(bc.CreatedOnUtc, DateTimeKind.Utc),
                        AllowViewingProfiles = _customerSettings.AllowViewingProfiles && bc.Customer != null && !bc.Customer.IsGuest(),
                        CommentParentID = bc.CommentParentID,//Netra
                    };
                    //Netra
                    var comments = _blogService.GetBlogComments(bc.CommentParentID);
                    if (comments != null)
                    {
                        commentModel.ChildCommentList = new List<BlogComment>(); 
                        foreach (var cmnt in comments)
                        {
                            commentModel.ChildCommentList.Add(cmnt);
                        }
                    }

                    if (_customerSettings.AllowCustomersToUploadAvatars)
                    {
                        var customer = bc.Customer;
                        string avatarUrl = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(customer.GetAttribute<int>(SystemCustomerAttributeNames.AvatarPictureId), _mediaSettings.AvatarPictureSize, false);
                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(avatarUrl) && _customerSettings.DefaultAvatarEnabled)
                            avatarUrl = _pictureService.GetDefaultPictureUrl(_mediaSettings.AvatarPictureSize, PictureType.Avatar);
                        commentModel.CustomerAvatarUrl = avatarUrl;
                    }
                    model.Comments.Add(commentModel);
                }
            }
        }
```

BlogComment is class which describes the properties.

```
 public partial class BlogComment : CustomerContent
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the comment text
        /// </summary>
        public virtual string CommentText { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the blog post identifier
        /// </summary>
        public virtual int BlogPostId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the blog post
        /// </summary>
        public virtual BlogPost BlogPost { get; set; }

        public virtual int CommentParentID { get; set; } //netra
    }
```

Comment: This error depends on how you pass the model to the view. can you post the code where you are passing the model to the view?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a null somewhere - you need to find out what's null and make it so it's not null; or change the Razor code to something like:

```
@if(Model.blogcommentmodel != null && Model.blogcommentmodel.ChildCommentList != null)
{
  @* original @foreach statement here *@
}
```

Comment: You forgot a ` != null` after `&& Model.blogcomentmodel.ChildCommentList`.

That is the correct way to program that code in order to ensure the "NullReferenceException" never gets thrown in your View. However, with my answer regarding having a default constructor that sets the ChildCommentList to a new List every time, it will always be set. *** Even with that code, you should still have all of the "!= null" on those. ***

Comment: have corrected the missing null check, thanks - but as for the other part of your comment, that's why I said that a way should be found to make sure there are no nulls. imho beyond that there's no definitive way to provide a good strategy for that in an answer because the question is too 'woolly' in that respect and almost qualifies for a close vote because of it.

Comment: Sorry, that second half of my comment was more for the OP. I had forgotten that line breaks don't work in the comments. I do agree with your assessment of the question.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you need to create a default constructor for your model. In the constructor, set `ChildCommentList = new List<BlogComment>();`.

It looks like you didn't set that in your Controller, which the way that you have your Model set up, would cause ChildCommentList to still be null. With that default constructor, you won't have to worry about your code breaking like this if you miss setting it somewhere.

To answer wnetra's comment, the constructor is on the BlogcommentModel class. So you'll need something like this:

```
public class BlogcommentModel {
    /* All of the property declarations */
    public IList<BlogComment> ChildCommentList { get; set; }

    /* Constructor for the BlogcommentModel class */
    public BlogcommentModel() {
        ChildcommentList = new List<BlogComment>();
    }
}
```

Any reference objects should always be instantiated inside a default constructor to ensure they won't be null when trying to reference them in code.

Also see Andras' answer with regard to always doing `!= null` when trying to reference reference objects in your code.

Comment: ChildCommentList is the property of BlogcommentModel.How i can create contructor for that?

Comment: I updated my answer as this includes a bigger block of code than should fit inside a comment.

Comment: :Error:Error Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'System.Collections.Generic.IList<Nop.Core.Domain.Blogs.BlogComment>

Comment: Are you using more than 1 type of Enumerable collection that would cause you to use IList as opposed to List (or another type of collection)? If you can just use List (or whichever else you are using), set it as one of those.

You SHOULD still be able to set it as `new List<BlogComment>();` and change it to a different implementation of IList later, though that is something I've never done.

Comment: How? can you please provide an example

Comment: I implement your code but still it giving me error in view.Is i need to remove property 'public BlogCommentModel blogcommentmodel { get; set; }' from BlogPostModel?

Answer (score 0):

I have removed following code from BlogCommenmodel :

```
//public int CommentParentID { get; set; }

    //public IList<BlogComment> ChildCommentList { get; set; }//netra

    //public BlogCommentModel()
    //{
    //    ChildCommentList = new List<BlogComment>();
    //}
```

and introduced in BlogPostModel

```
 [Validator(typeof(BlogPostValidator))]
public partial class BlogPostModel : BaseNopEntityModel
{
    public BlogPostModel()
    {
        Tags = new List<string>();
        Comments = new List<BlogCommentModel>();
        AddNewComment = new AddBlogCommentModel();
        ChildCommentList = new List<BlogComment>();
    }

    public string SeName { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Body { get; set; }

    public bool AllowComments { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfComments { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

    public IList<string> Tags { get; set; }

    public IList<BlogCommentModel> Comments { get; set; }
    public AddBlogCommentModel AddNewComment { get; set; }


    //Netra
    public int CommentParentID { get; set; }

    public IList<BlogComment> ChildCommentList { get; set; }//netra

   // public BlogCommentModel blogcommentmodel { get; set; }
}
```

IN View:

```
<div>
                            @if (Model.ChildCommentList != null)
                            {
                                foreach (var childcomments in Model.ChildCommentList)
                                {
                                    @Html.Raw(Nop.Core.Html.HtmlHelper.FormatText(childcomments.CommentText, false, true, false, false, false, false))
                                }
                            }
                        </div>
```

Comment: Did that help any? I don't know what error you were getting in the code after having added the constructor. That should have removed the possibility of nulls. there might have been something else going on.